# manage.py - not in project folder?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-manage.py, manage.py

I'm trying out Django for the first time, and I'm trying to follow [the tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/) provided by the django team.

After I've created a new project I get the following folder/file structure, just as the tutorial says I should:

```
mysite/
    manage.py
    mysite/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
```

When I create an app I run:

```
python manage.py startapp polls
```

...which creates the app 'polls' in the same folder as the manage.py file - which gives me:

```
mysite/
    manage.py
    polls/
        __init__.py
        admin.py
        models.py
        tests.py
        views.py
    mysite/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
```

This means the app I created gets created outside my project folder, which, of course, should not be the case. I have tried to move manage.py inside the project folder. But when I do that and run:

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

...I get the following error:

```
raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" %     (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
ImportError: Could not import settings 'testproject.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No     module named testproject.settings
```

I guess I could move the app manually to the project folder, but this is something I shouldn't have to do.

So, either something is wrong in the tutorial (which I have very hard to believe), or I'm missing something out here (more likely).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the site structure you posted the actual structure, or an example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the new proper layout. "mysite/mysite" is an app, and "mysite/polls" is an app. The "mysite" parent folder is your project folder.

Comment: Whether it's correct or not, Django's not finding his settings file. That's indicative of something being wrong somewhere.

Comment: he said it can't find it *after* he moved manage.py into mysite/mysite.

Comment: Ok, now I understand. Got really confused there for awhile. Thanks!

Comment: For some additional details see the Docs here (the layout changed in version 1.5): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/#creating-a-project

Answer (score 3):

@holyredbeard that is the correct layout are you reading the older documentation?

Useful reading: http://www.tdd-django-tutorial.com/blog/articles/2012/tutorials-updated-django-14-and-its-weird-new-fold/

Don't move the manage.py it should sit outside the apps and the project folder.

since 1.4 common layout example...

```
project_root/
   project_name/
       media/
       static/
       static_root/ (in production)
       templates/some_app/foo.html (overriding some_app at project level)
                /admin/some_app/some_model/change_list.html
                (overriding admin changelist for some_app.models.some_model)
       settings.py
       settings_deployment.py
       urls.py
   some_app/
       templates/some_app/foo.html
       urls.py
       views.py
       models.py
   manage.py
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the official layout since version 1.4.

The rationale behind is explained well in the release notes:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/#updated-default-project-layout-and-manage-py

Do not move `manage.py`. In general you can expect that Django's own scripts always do the right thing, you never need to move any files just to get it working.